# Method to find folder was renamed recently. Java

Tags: java, directory

I am making a Folder Synchronization application. I am stuck in the design that how should i know that folder has been renamed recently. I am using Java watch service api to know the rename. But if the service is not running. And application is offline then how should i get to know that a folder was renamed when the service was offline.

Comment: Don't quote me on this but is there a date changed parameter on folders?  Would there be one for the name change as well (specifically)?

Comment: there is somefolder.lastmodified() function available . but it does not tell when was the folder renamed. It only tells the time of changing within the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep a tree saved somewhere (database maybe) which reflects the folder structure at a given time. After that you just have to rescan and calculate the deltas when your app starts up.

Comment: Or the most obvious one. :)